# StackedAndGroupedColumn series value for both stack

Tags: highcharts

Hello in a stacked grouped column chart how is it possible to have values of one series for both stacks?
What i would like to achieve is Group the Stacks by Customer which is simple.
But in my case i have values of different commodities for both stacks.
I have created the following jsfiddle example which explains a little bit better the problem. 
[link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y64w/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Stacked Grouped'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Customer1', 'Customer2']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },

       bar: {
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
          }
       }

        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Iron Ore',
            data: [5, 3],
            stack: 'today',
       }, {
            name: 'Manetite',
            data: [3, 4],
            stack: 'yesterday'
        },
                {
            name: 'Iron Ore',
            data: [5, 3],
            stack: 'today'
        }, {
            name: 'Manetite',
            data: [3, 4],
            stack: 'yesterday'
        }]
    });
});
```

As you can see the commodities are doubled in this way but i want them on both stacks.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use x/y parameters

```
{
            x: 0, //number of group
            y: 3
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y64w/2/

Comment: Thank you very much but I would need Iron Ore and Magnetite on all columns not on different ones. Customer 1 has x amount of Iron Ore Today and had Yesterday. Same for Customer 2. Sorry if i was not clear.

Comment: so you need to have this values duplicated in all series.

Comment: What i would need is Customer 1 StackedBar1 with IronOre value + Magnetite value.  Customer 1 StackedBar2 with IronOre value + Magnetite value. Customer 2 StackedBar1 with IronOre value + Magnetite value.  Customer 2 StackedBar2 with IronOre value + Magnetite value. Thank you.